# how to add multiple ports dynamically to gojs node

Tags: javascript, gojs

I am working on `go.js` flowchart my nodes are:

1. Start
2. Play
3. Que
4. Options
5. End

Start node has one output port whereas both ***play*** and ***que*** have one input and one output port,and the ***options*** node has one input port and can have one to multiple output ports at the bottom based upon user input.

Whenever User drags options node from Palette and drops it on the diagram,a popup appears which asks for user input.

So basically what I want now is to create options node's output ports based on user input.
Is there any way I can achieve this?

Below attached is the screenshot of what I have done so far and what I am trying to achieve

[image]

[image]

Here is My Code

```
    function show_options_opt(model,dat,node,myDiagram)
    {
     //this function is called whenever the option node is dropped to diagram div
     var portSize = new go.Size(8, 8);
    model.setDataProperty(data,'bottomArray',[]);
  $$=go.GraphObject.make;
  var portMenu =  // context menu for each port
  $$(go.Adornment, "Vertical",
    makeButton("Remove port",
               // in the click event handler, the obj.part is the Adornment;
               // its adornedObject is the port
               function (e, obj) { removePort(obj.part.adornedObject); }),
    makeButton("Change color",
               function (e, obj) { changeColor(obj.part.adornedObject); }),
    makeButton("Remove side ports",
               function (e, obj) { removeAll(obj.part.adornedObject); })
  );
   myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
  $$(go.Node, "Table",
    { locationObjectName: "BODY",
      locationSpot: go.Spot.Center,
      selectionObjectName: "BODY"
    },
     new go.Binding("location", "loc",go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
  $$(go.Panel, "Horizontal",
      new go.Binding("itemArray", "bottomArray"),
      { row: 2, column: 1,
        itemTemplate:
          $$(go.Panel,
            { _side: "bottom",
              fromSpot: go.Spot.Bottom, toSpot: go.Spot.Bottom,
              fromLinkable: true, toLinkable: true, cursor: "pointer",
              contextMenu: portMenu },
            new go.Binding("portId", "portId"),
            $$(go.Shape, "Rectangle",
              { stroke: null, strokeWidth: 0,
                desiredSize: portSize,
                margin: new go.Margin(0, 1) },
              new go.Binding("fill", "portColor"))
          )  // end itemTemplate
      }
    )  // end Horizontal Panel
   );
  addPort("bottom",node,myDiagram);
   }//end function show_options_opt
```

And Below Given is the addport function

```
   function addPort(side,node,myDiagram) {
  myDiagram.startTransaction("addPort");
  // skip any selected Links
  if (!(node instanceof go.Node)) return;
  // compute the next available index number for the side
  var i = 0;
  while (node.findPort(side + i.toString()) !== node) i++;
  // now this new port name is unique within the whole Node because of the side prefix
  var name = side + i.toString();
  // get the Array of port data to be modified
  var arr = node.data[side + "Array"];
  if (arr) {
    // create a new port data object
    var newportdata = {
      portId: name,
      portColor: go.Brush.randomColor()
      // if you add port data properties here, you should copy them in copyPortData above
    };
    // and add it to the Array of port data
    myDiagram.model.insertArrayItem(arr, -1, newportdata);
  }
    myDiagram.commitTransaction("addPort");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a variable number of objects (including in your case ports) in a node, you'll want to bind [**Panel.itemArray**](https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Panel.html#itemArray) to an Array in your node data which holds one data object for each port.  This is described in [Item Arrays](https://gojs.net/latest/intro/itemArrays.html).  There are several samples that demonstrate how to do this.  The [Dynamic Ports](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/dynamicPorts.html) sample might be most instructive, although you'll want to strip out a lot of the code because it has four separate Arrays of port data, each bound to four different Panels, whereas presumably you only need one Panel of ports bound to one Array of port data.

Comment: sir i tried to understand the concept through dynamic ports example,which i found to be rather abstruse than easy or clear..however i tried writing the code for creating just only one port on the options node but still i get nothing.i am editing my question and putting my recently written code there kindly have a look at it and help me achieve my target Thankx.

Comment: This code is creating the node with port id bottom0 but the port is not shwoing on the node kindly help